# Trouble creating a generic make file

Tags: c, makefile

Hey so I'm a little new to makefiles and I'm trying to make a generic makefile that will compile whatever files end with .c in the current directory, instead of specifically named files for a project. I've searched a few places, re-read my lecture notes, tried a few changes and I can't seem to get it working. Here's what I have:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -o
%.o : %.c
        gcc ${CFLAGS} .c $<
```

This is the error I keep getting when I try to run it:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I would be grateful for any help really, I really despise typing in `gcc` over and over!
The file is named `Makefile`

Comment: What is the exact command line you type when you "try to run it"?

Comment: I type just "make" (without quotes)

Comment: @Karysto FYI: have you looked at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)?

Comment: No, but I will now, thanks to everyone for the help. I really love this helpful community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > a generic makefile that will compile whatever files end with .c in the current directory

This is an atypical use for `make`, but can be done using GNU make's text functions:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))
all: $(OBJS)
```

If you have `foo.c` and `bar.c` in your directory, running `make` will produce `foo.o` and `bar.o`.

If you meant that you want the command `make` to compile and link each .c into an executable, try:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
EXECS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SOURCES))
all: $(EXECS)
```

What is more typical, is to want to compile and link a single program. In that case, you don't need any makefile whatsoever, just run these commands:

```
make foo
make bar
```

Comment: I actually tried just `make myTest.c` and got the same output as above, `make: Nothing to be done for `myTest.c'.` I'm going to try the wildcard code, I haven't seen it very much at the moment.

Comment: Holy jeez that second block of code worked..exactly what I needed. I'm going to read into using wildcard more, thank you very much!

Comment: @Karysto You should read more into using makefiles. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

The [wildcard](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) function can be used to compile all C source files in the directory and then link them together.

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -o
SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
foo: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: won't that only compile hello.c though? I've never seen the second last block of code with the $(EXEC)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax errors, and your makefile builds the objects but doesn't link the objects into an executable.

myTest.c:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

makefile if your source file is "myTest.c":

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g

all: myTest

myTest: myTest.o
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o : %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Build with

```
make myTest
gcc -Wall -g -c myTest.c
gcc -Wall -g myTest.o -o myTest
```

Comment: Every line after the third is redundant -- those rules are provided by default.

Comment: How am I going to teach the asker about makefiles with only the first three lines?

Comment: Hey, I appreciate all the quick answers! I tried the code above in Bash and I got the following: $> make myTest.c
$> `Makefile:6: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: On the indented lines, makes sure there is a tab instead of spaces. Also type "make myTest" not "make myTest.c"

Comment: Yes I added the tabs just now (noob mistake), and got this output: `make: Nothing to be done for `myTest.c'.`

Comment: I wrote up "myTest.c" and did "make myTest" to discover the issue. "-o" doesn't belong in the CFLAGS. Fixed in my example.